# Sanitization in CI for Database

Tags: php, codeigniter

In CI you have Validation Rules, Active Record and Input; library / helpers that sanitize data for you.

When you receive data via post all you need to do is $this->input->post('id', TRUE); and you can be sure that 'id' is safe to use.

Validation rules has same ability that helps you to check if string is xss clean but can also help you to validate information which is beneficial.

At the same time, if data to go into DB, active record escapes each variable information that you push into database to prevent mysql injection.

The question is, what reasons are their to use form validate on 'id' element, which is used to display an information about product on the page?

How i see it, because DB escapes string it is safe to push 'id' straight into DB and have an if statement in controller to verify that any data was found in DB. So I am interested in the confirmation if what below works or potentially some further ideas.

The reason why I am asking this question is because I remember reading that apparently CI didn't have sufficient sanitization in place and activerecord cannot be trusted? Due to that I dont trust myself to perform CRUD operations in such a way.

Here is an example

Controller:

```
public function view(){
   $result = $this->product_model->getById($this->input->post('id'));

   if($result == FALSE){ redirect('previous page'); }

   $this->load->view('work/proof_read/view', array('product' => $result));
}
```

Model

```
public function getById($product_id){
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('products');
   $this->db->where('id', $product_id);

   $query = $this->db->get();
   if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
      return $query->result_array();
   }

   return FALSE; 
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand, but I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Broadly speaking, you should usually validate anything from users with at least the XSS, Trim, and a maximum characters.

Comment: I remember reading that CI had a poorly written active record library due to which is best to use form_validation to process input before pushing into DB. my thinking is if project / function doesn't require a high level of error handling we can do minimal validation and let mysql deal with the data and return true / false... if lets say you looking for a blog post #12 and only user with id #77 can view it because blog belongs to user #77 we can have a mysql where statement with user = 77 and blog_id = 12, and if mysql found nothing than we have a problem with user input and we return false.

Answer (score 1):

Form validation in CodeIgniter only validates the data coming from the form, such as strings, emails, phone numbers and more. The database portion doesn't validate anything necessarily. It only escapes quotes and makes it safe (loosely) for it to insert into the database.

I say loosely. Your database engine has the final say. If you're trying to insert into a purely numeric field, it won't accept a string validated by the CodeIgniter form library.

In your controller example, you'll need to check that your $this->input->post('id') is numeric or at least it exists as an id in your database.

Comment: Hey Cody, thanks for your reply. In regards to your last paragraph, this is kind of what i was talking about, the thing is that a function in the model handles the validation of $this->input->post('id') for me: 1. ID is checked by Codeigniter to make sure that its xss clear in the Controller; 2. Model function checks if id exists in the database; 3. Going back to point 2 if ID is not numeric or doesn't exists function will return false; 4. If check has been successful Model will return a set of data. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Yes. I think I understand your question better. You might use the validated form value elsewhere in your code, rather than only pushing it to the database. In addition, the database checking in Active Record might be specifically geared towards database activities. Just some thoughts.